# How to apply material correctly to such kind of shape?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I want to apply material to such kind of shape,it's made by GN.
[image]

I download material from other place.
But when I apply it onto model,it works bad.

The material should look like this
[image]

But it looks like this in my demo
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I have done is change this
[image]

I don't know what's wrong with it.
Keeping geometry-nodes, and don't apply it into editable vertice will be better.
Thanks.

Update the profile.
[image]

Comment: it is very helpful that you included the blend file. Unfortunately you did not pack resources before uploading so we cannot see your texture, but just "pink" ;)

Comment: @Chris,updated.Thanks for your advice,it's the first time I know that resources can be packed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably only two option here ...

- **Generated** texture coordinates with *Texture* node set to **Sphere** projection.

[image]

or

- **UV unwrap** node ... just manipulation under GN is quite limited

[image]
[image]
[image]

[For more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02XNGOVpSV4&t=486s) about UV under GN

---

In general I would say just *Box* projection should work the best, but it didn't ...