# different output in rendered view and material preview

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes

I tried researching for question [How to apply material correctly to such kind of shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274028/how-to-apply-material-correctly-to-such-kind-of-shape).

So i made this:

[image]

which looks like this in material preview:

[image]

but in rendered view my textures are "gone"!? what can cause that?

[image]

blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hello, in Rendered mode it will reflect the image called je_gray_02_4k.exr but you haven't shared it

Comment: oh sorry, will correct that

Comment: blend file updated

Comment: Possibly a bug with GN? I added a new cylinder and modeled it directly then added your material to it and the textures appear fine.  
Also setting to Eevee the textures are fine with your models

Comment: @Psyonic Not really a bug, I'm working on the answer.

Comment: ok....waiting......... :D

Comment: @Psyonic I guess it works in _Eevee_ for the same reason (whatever that might be) why it works in the _Material Preview_, since the _Material Preview_ uses _Eevee_.

Comment: @Chris What are you waiting for? It's been ready forever now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the attribute name you are using. You have a *Vector* output in the *Geometry Nodes* modifier that's called "uv", and that's the name you are using in the *Attribute* node in the *Shader Editor*. I checked if there is some spelling error or anything but it's all correct.

[image: attribute uv]

You also have a *Texture Coordinate* node in the material. I checked all outputs and all of them showed the texture (incorrectly mapped, but visible) excluding one: the *UV* output. It actually looks like before with the attribute.

[image: UV coordinate]

So I got the idea that maybe the *Cycles* render engine uses the attribute uv internally for the UV map? The *Material Preview* works with *Eevee*, no problems there as it seems. I have no idea about the details inside Blender, but I just made a little test and decided to rename the attribute to "test" in both the modifier and the material and then it worked (in the object to the left I changed it before making screenshots):

[image: renamed attribute]

Comment: @Chris It looks like it might be best when using attributes (and you can't find a reason it doesn't work) to not give them meaningful names making sense, but totally crazy and absolutely unrelated names to ensure they are not colliding with some other attributes :D

Comment: wow, chapeau for finding that!!!

Comment: @Chris ...but I'm really curious what the real reason is. Is _Cycles_ actually grabbing the UV map when you use the attribute name? And if so, why doesn't _Eevee_ mess it up? Why can _Eevee_ distinct between them?

Comment: I have no clue…‍♂️